# Making an appointment

Tags: phrases

What phrases do you use to make the most nearest appointment with a doctor?

For example:

> When is the next available appointment?

or

> When is the (nearest, closest) appointment?

Comment: "When is the next free slot for an appointment ?"

Comment: Either of your suggestions will work, and many others.  "How soon can I get in?" is another.

Comment: @Turki "How soon can you book me in [for an appointment]?"

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence—"next available"—is correct.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to your first suggestion is "When is the first available appointment?"